# bind ctrl+insert in zsh?

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

What key combo do I use to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> in my zshrc? I tried entering quoted-insert mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> does not output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed in `URxVt` with

```
bindkey '^[[2^' zle-widget
```

and in `xterm` with

```
bindkey '^[[2;5~' zle-widget
```

As you can see, the string which needs to be bound is rather dependent on your terminal emulator (and yor X keybindings), not your shell.

The usual trick to get the key strings is to start `cat` and press the desired key combination:

```
$ cat
^[[2;5~
```

Additionally, the following escape sequences are recognised (from `man zshzle`) by `bindkey`

```
   \a     bell character
   \b     backspace
   \e, \E escape
   \f     form feed
   \n     linefeed (newline)
   \r     carriage return
   \t     horizontal tab
   \v     vertical tab
   \NNN   character code in octal
   \xNN   character code in hexadecimal
   \M[-]X character with meta bit set
   \C[-]X control character
   ^X     control character
```

Comment: I'm using gnome-terminal `^[[2;5~` did not work for me. How do I discover what string it uses?

Comment: @RedHatter: I added the usual way to my answer. However this does not work with `gnome-terminal`, it seems that Ctrl+Ins isn't passed to the running process at all. I tried to remove all key bindings in the terminal itself, but unfortunately this doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's too bad.... what about ctrl+tab? I remember reading somewhere that tab was ^I, but nether that nor ^[[^I work.

Comment: @RedHatter: You are right, `^I` is tab (and that's one rare case, where the `cat` trick doesn't work), but you can also use `\t`. However I wasn't able to bind Ctrl+Tab with xterm or urxvt, too.

Comment: @RedHatter: Although I appreciate that you accepted my answer, I recommend to undo that (your problem isn't solved) and change the question title to e.g. 'Bind Ctrl+Tab in Gnome Terminal'. I already added the corresponding tag yesterday as I'm pretty sure that's not a `zsh` issue (or are you able to bind this combination in bash?). That way you have better chances that a gnome expert will have a look -- I came here by the zsh tag and even had to ,,conquer'' a colleague's machine as I don't have gnome-terminal installed myself ;)